# Plotly - how do I highlight the path to a node on hover?

Tags: python, plotly

I have a graph that looks like this:

[image]

The segment of code that generates the graph looks something like this:

```
import sys
import os

import numpy
import itertools
from lxml import etree 
import lxml.html

import re

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pygraphviz

from networkx.drawing.nx_agraph import graphviz_layout

import plotly.graph_objects as go

G = nx.DiGraph()

#nodes and edges added around here

pos=graphviz_layout(G, prog='dot')

edge_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=edge_x, y=edge_y,
    line=dict(width=0.5, color='#888'),
    hoverinfo='none',
    mode='lines')

node_trace = go.Scatter(
    x=node_x, y=node_y,
    mode='markers',
    hoverinfo='text',
    marker=dict(size=10,line_width=2)
    )
            
node_trace.marker.color = color_list
node_trace.text = node_text

config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})

fig = go.Figure(data=[edge_trace, node_trace],
             layout=go.Layout(
                title='Comparison Results: ',
                titlefont_size=16,
                showlegend=False,
                hovermode='closest',
                margin=dict(b=80,l=10,r=10,t=40),
                annotations=[ dict(
                    text="",
                    showarrow=False,
                    xref="paper", yref="paper",
                    x=0.005, y=-0.002 ) ],
                xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False),
                yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, zeroline=False, showticklabels=False))
                )

fig.update_layout(dragmode='pan')

fig.show(config=config)
```

How do I make it so that when I hover over a node, the path all the way to the root node is highlighted?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!